# Is there any way to convert SKDocument to SKbitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, skiasharp

i am looking for a way to convert a SKDocument which has created a pdf just like this `SKDocument.CreatePdf(ManagedStreamForPdfMemoryStream);` to an image equivalent like `SKBitmap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, the `SKDocument.CreatePdf` generates a PDF file that cannot be read a a bitmap with SkiaSharp.

As I mention in this answer, I would suggest looking for ways to load PDFs without associating with SkiaSharp - they are different tasks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59513162/1117914

BUT...

If you are creating a PDF using SkiaSharp, then just use that same logic you used to create the PDF to create the bitmaps.

You can even use something like the `SKNWayCanvas` to draw in parallel: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/skiasharp.sknwaycanvas

```
var pdf = document.BeginPage();
var bmp = imageSurface.Canvas;

var canvas = new SKNWayCanvas(100, 100);
canvas.AddCanvas(pdf);
canvas.AddCanvas(bmp);

canvas.DrawRect(...);
```

At the end, you will have a PDF and a set of bitmaps that you can render on screen. No extra work required and no need to load files.